# How to make a 4 digit integer

Tags: java, integer

I want to make an integer value from the range 1-9999.
But the integer values should be always in 4 digits.

Like 0001, 0002, 0015, 0156, 1578

Comment: You'd need to use a string pad function, or you could have a string with some numeric characters. My guess is the former is what you're looking for.

Comment: You are mixing up different concepts. Integers are just **numbers**. And 1, as a number is always that: a 1. It doesn't know about "leading zeros". What you are talking about is a **string** representing a number. Because then, strings can have a fixed length, and then you might add leading zeros to enhance "number 1" to "0001".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably use String format of the integer you willing to, like this:

```
String.format("%04d", your integer));
```

This will always show missing 0 on the left on digits like 01 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.format("%04d%n", n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print 4 digit integer:

```
System.out.printf("%04d%n",your integer);
```

If you want to store in a variable:

```
String str=String.format("%04d", your integer));
```

[Read more details about String format()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format)